# both or either in negative sentences?

Tags: grammar

Hello native English speakers!

I want to ask you about *either* and *both*.
I tried to find similar questions in this site but I think they were not same with these ones.

My questions are;

1. I was invited to two parties, but I couldn't go to ------- of them.
2. I took two books with me on holidays, but I didn't read ------- of
       them.

I choose *both* for questions 1 and 2. But the right answers were *either*.
But I think *both* and *either* are correct either. Am I right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Both options can be correct, but they really mean something different. So the question is, what was the context of the questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"I was invited to two parties, but I couldn't go to both of them."* - this suggests that you were able to go to one of them, but not both - perhaps they were on at the same time, for example.

*"I was invited to two parties, but I couldn't go to either of them."* - this states that you could go to none of the parties.

So, you can see that the meaning is quite different.  Both are grammatically correct, so either could be correct depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you very much Max and others for detailed explanation! All the answers were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd say "either". If you were to say something like "I took two books with me, and I *did* read them both", you'd say "both". I am fairly sure this is the only difference between the two.

Comment: "I couldn't read either" has a different meaning to "I couldn't read both" - see my answer.